# Java Github Api to compare a specific file from a previous commit to current version of that file in master

Tags: java, git, github, github-api

I have some commit made in the past with a commit SHA. This commit is made to master. The commit includes changes made to file A,B and C. How do I use the Github API to compare the file B in the past commit to it's current version on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [commit compare API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) to compare two commits. It's not currently possible to limit this comparison to just a single file, so you will need to do some filtering of the returned results.